# Styling the DatePicker from MUI

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using a DatePicker component from Mui Lab and I am trying to style the Calendar component by adding some border or background color. I used the PaperProps prop for DatePicker but it's not styling it. Trying to understand why I cant just use an SX prop for it

[this is the calendar where i want to add a border to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJ6gm.png)

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { TextField } from '@material-ui/core';
import { alpha } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import DatePicker from '@material-ui/lab/DatePicker';
import { AppBorderStyle } from '../theme';

export const DateField = (props) => {
  const {
    error,
    fullWidth,
    helperText,
    label,
    onChange,
    onBlur,
    placeholder,
    disabled,
    value,
    name,
    ...other
  } = props;

  return (
    <DatePicker
      PopperProps={{
        sx: {
          '& .MuiPaper-root': {
            backgroundColor: 'red',
            border: '1px solid black',
          }
        }
      }}
      onChange={onChange}
      renderInput={({ InputProps, ...rest }) => (
        <TextField
          {...rest}
          disabled={disabled}
          onBlur={onBlur}
          name={name}
          error={error}
          fullWidth={fullWidth}
          helperText={helperText}
          label={label}
          placeholder={placeholder}
          sx={{
            '& .MuiFilledInput-root': {
              backgroundColor: 'background.paper',
              borderRadius: 1,
              border: AppBorderStyle,
              px: 1.5,
              py: 0.75,
              transition: (theme) => theme.transitions.create([
                'border-color',
              ]),
              '&:hover': {
                backgroundColor: 'background.paper'
              },
              '&.Mui-focused': {
                backgroundColor: 'background.paper',
                boxShadow: (theme) => `${alpha(theme.palette.primary.main,
                  0.25)} 0 0 0 0.2rem`
              },
              '& .MuiFilledInput-input': {
                fontSize: 14,
                height: 'unset',
                lineHeight: 1.6,
                p: 0
              },
              '&.Mui-disabled': {
                backgroundColor: 'action.disabledBackground',
                boxShadow: 'none',
                borderColor: alpha('#D6DBE1', 0.5)
              }
            }
          }}
          variant="filled"
          InputProps={{
            disableUnderline: true,
            ...InputProps
          }}
          InputLabelProps={{
            shrink: true,
            sx: {
              color: 'text.primary',
              fontSize: 14,
              fontWeight: 500,
              mb: 0.5,
              position: 'relative',
              transform: 'none'
            }
          }}
        />
      )}
      value={value}
      {...other}
    />
  );
};

DateField.defaultProps = {
  disabled: false,
};

DateField.propTypes = {
  disabled: PropTypes.bool,
  error: PropTypes.bool,
  fullWidth: PropTypes.bool,
  helperText: PropTypes.string,
  label: PropTypes.string,
  name: PropTypes.string,
  onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  onBlur: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  placeholder: PropTypes.string,
  value: PropTypes.instanceOf(Date)
};
```

Answer (score 3):

I noticed you're using depecrated version of mui as you can check [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material-ui/core). For newer versions of material UI components, we import material components from `@mui` and not from `@material-ui`.

I'm not sure if the classes are the same in your version or not. But the issue for your case looks like you are targeting the wrong class to add a border. You need to target `MuiPickersPopper-root` class to change the border.

```
PopperProps={{
        sx: {'&.MuiPickersPopper-root': {border: '4px solid red'},},
      }}
```

I created a solution of DatePicker with the border [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tcysgk?file=src/App.js). Cheers!

Comment: your example seems to be broken

Answer (score 1):

Update, that's how you do it on mui v5:

```
slotProps={{
      popper: {
        sx: {
          ".MuiPaper-root": { border: "1px solid blue", borderRadius: "10px" },
        },
      },
    }}
```